# Import custom font

Tags: html, css, fonts

New to CSS, made a custom font [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and downloaded the result.

CSS importing the font:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'intro_script_demomedium';
  src: local('intro_script_demomedium'), url('./webfontkit-20220509-064009/introscriptdemo-medium.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

This doesn't do anything...

Comment: Have you assigned it to a style?

Answer (score 1):

remove that local part it's not necessary and causing your problem

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'intro_script_demomedium'; 
    src: url('./webfontkit-20220509-064009/introscriptdemo-medium.woff2') format('woff2');
}
body{
    font-family: 'intro_script_demomedium';
}
```

this is all you need,
if it didn't work, check the browser console for a `404` error in case that your address might be wrong, let me know if it didn't work anyway